# PayPal Express Checkout.js - send custom parameters

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

How I can send a custom parameter to new Paypal Express checkout. I need to send the `booking_id` and get the same after success full payment.

I have gone through the paypal official [document](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/), but can't found how we can send?

Please see below is my file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    <script>
        paypal.Button.render({
            env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production
            client: {
                sandbox:    'AYbCnvobq09Ptmsd1TRp3019CMrSTyaAmrHNv6ox0jl86H9OZFmGCPqHqqfPtqpTYTiIuy_e5UGnclMw',
                //production: '<insert production client id>'
            },
            commit: true,
            payment: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
            }
        }, '#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have solved issues, we can pass the parameters in the payment method. like the below code:

```
payment: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.create({
        payment: {
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: { total: '10', currency: 'USD' },
                    custom: '1452'
                }
            ]
        }
    });
},
```

Hope this will help for developers.

Comment: Any idea if I can make that dynamic? I have a text field next to my button that may change.

Comment: @Tiago Yes you can make that dynamic, are  you using `$_POST` or want to get data from database.

Comment: Fully client-side in JS. Right now I have the old hosted button system, with an input field that stays in sync with an email field. When the user types a custom email, this field is populated and sent with the payment process. By default I use the buyer's email from the IPN to create an account, but they have this text field to provide an optional custom email. Ideal is if I can have a similar email field hidden in the dynamic JS button. Does this make sense? Thanks for responding!

Comment: You can proceed with this example is [here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/confirm) with the `onAuthorize` method of Checkout.js.

Comment: Interesting, I see what you mean. Thanks. Although is there no way I can populate this parameter after the button is rendered, before the button is clicked? I'd like this info in the IPN. Would also be nice to keep this less steps if possible. Maybe this merits a proper question here on SO...

Answer (score 1):

To invoice number use:

```
      payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: {
                                    total: '200',
                                    currency: 'BRL'
                            },
                            invoice_number: 100

                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Comment: How you have passed the `invoice_number: 100`, it will return from Paypal?