# Paypal Express Checkout.js - pass custom values into transaction

Tags: javascript, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I am trying to set up a paypal Express instance and pass the order number from the website into the paypal transaction, so the client has a reference. This is how their previous system worked with express, but now we have rebuilt the site from scratch, not finding any helpful documentation from Paypal on custom values, or even passing a description in.

I have tried [PayPal Express Checkout.js - send custom parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923951/paypal-express-checkout-js-send-custom-parameters) and both solutions do absolutely nothing with my PayPal Sandbox. The notifications provided by paypal only include the account information and the payment amount, clearly this is not right?

i've been going off these docs: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Here is vanilla checkout.js client side checkout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <script>
        paypal.Button.render({

            env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

            // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
            // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
            client: {
                sandbox:    'AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R',
                production: '<insert production client id>'
            },

            // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
            commit: true,

            // payment() is called when the button is clicked
            payment: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },

            // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
            }

        }, '#paypal-button-container');

    </script>
</body>
```

I've tried forming the `data` object and passing it in but it either doesn't work or nothing happens at all. I've also tried adding onto the payment array, but nothing is happening on the PayPal sandbox end.

My receipts on the buyer account look like:
[image]

My Notification from the Store owner is:
[image]

How can I fill out the red circles? I need a product description of what the user just purchased, but also I need to pass in my order number from the website into paypal?  I literally can't find anything on paypal docs that helps with this.

Can someone be so kind to lead me in the right direction? I feel like im missing something simple

Answer (score 2):

I talked to paypal, they actually don't have direct documentation on this, they are still creating documentation for a lot of features.

You can utilize the JSON array within the cURL call example provided by paypal

```
 -d'{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
  "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
  {
    "amount": {
    "total": "30.11",
    "currency": "USD",
    "details": {
      "subtotal": "30.00",
      "tax": "0.07",
      "shipping": "0.03",
      "handling_fee": "1.00",
      "shipping_discount": "-1.00",
      "insurance": "0.01"
    }
    },
    "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
    "custom": "EBAY_EMS_90048630024435",
    "invoice_number": "48787589673",
    "payment_options": {
    "allowed_payment_method": "INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE"
    },
    "soft_descriptor": "ECHI5786786",
    "item_list": {
    "items": [
      {
      "name": "hat",
      "description": "Brown color hat",
      "quantity": "5",
      "price": "3",
      "tax": "0.01",
      "sku": "1",
      "currency": "USD"
      },
      {
      "name": "handbag",
      "description": "Black color hand bag",
      "quantity": "1",
      "price": "15",
      "tax": "0.02",
      "sku": "product34",
      "currency": "USD"
      }
    ],
    "shipping_address": {
      "recipient_name": "Hello World",
      "line1": "4thFloor",
      "line2": "unit#34",
      "city": "SAn Jose",
      "country_code": "US",
      "postal_code": "95131",
      "phone": "011862212345678",
      "state": "CA"
    }
    }
  }
  ],
  "note_to_payer": "Contact us for any questions on your order.",
  "redirect_urls": {
  "return_url": "https://example.com",
  "cancel_url": "https://example.com"
  }
}'
```

so for the `"description": "Brown color hat",`

```
transactions: [
                {
                    amount: { total: $paying, currency: 'CAD' },
                    description: 'This is a test description',
                }
              ]
```

I don't know why the solution presented in [PayPal Express Checkout.js - send custom parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923951/paypal-express-checkout-js-send-custom-parameters) did not work for me, probably my syntax issue or a caching issue, but it's working today! (of course...)